# Why when adding RequireComponent attribute it's not adding the component in the editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class MoveObject : MonoBehaviour
```

It's not adding the LineRenderer not in editor mode and not in run time.

Comment: How exactly are you attaching your component? And no on runtime or in editor scripts it has no effect at all only for attaching it via the Inspector

Comment: are you script added to a GameObject?

Comment: this attribute is more about "do not allow attach this component if another is not present yet" rathar than "attach automatically the required component", so that you can't add your component programmatically before the other required one. When in edit mode, Unity Editor is smart to add the required component automatically for you, but this is an editor feature not something that you actually can always rely on, and for sure not meant to be used at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be totally sure rather use [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html)

```
[SerializeField] private LineRenderer _line;

private void OnValidate()
{
    if(!_line && !TryGetComponent<LineRenderer>(out _line))
    {
        _line = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }
}
```

and for runtime do the same thing also in `Awake`

```
private void Awake ()
{
    if(!_line && !TryGetComponent<LineRenderer>(out _line))
    {
        _line = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }
}
```

You could also make this an extension method like e.g.

```
public static class ComponentExtensions
{
    public static void EnsureComponent<T>(this Component component, ref T output) where T : Component
    {
        if(!output && !component.TryGetComponent<T>(out output))
        {
            output = component.gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

and use

```
this.EnsureComponent<LineRenderer>(ref _line);
```

in your component scripts.